# Creating shared pointer from this pointer

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior

Below code gives segmentation fault as expected.

```
struct B{
    shared_ptr<B> createShared(){ return shared_ptr<B>(this);}
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<B> p1 = make_shared<B>();
    shared_ptr<B> p2 = p1->createShared();
    return 0;
}
```

but when I change the code

```
shared_ptr<B> p1 = make_shared<B>();
        to
shared_ptr<B> p1(new B);
```

program compiles and runs without any crash.

Can someone explain me what exactly is causing the change in behavior between these two cases.

**Note:-** I know that it is not the right way to create the shared pointer from this pointer, what I am looking for is the reason for change in behavior between these two cases. Compiler I used is clang++-3.8 and g++-5.4.

Comment: You should read about [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). The reference also explains what happens with code such as your `createShared` function (hint: it leads to *undefined behavior*).

Answer (score 0):

Running without crashing doesn't mean your program is correct. When you hit undefined behavior the result is undefined. Both versions of your program destroy the same object twice because you basically create two separate shared_ptrs from the same raw pointer. So one of those tries to delete an invalid pointer which results in undefined behavior.

There is actually a difference between the two ways of creating a shared_ptr. Let's consider `shared_ptr<B> p1(new B);`, it first allocates a B then initializes the shared_ptr with the raw ptr to B. During initialization of the shared_ptr a control block is allocated containing a use count and a synchronization object. So that are two separate allocations. `make_shared` however allocates a single block large enough to hold both the control block and the actual object so the resulting memory layout is a little different and the cleanup code also works slightly different.

As Some programmer dude mentioned you should use [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: I understand the point that in both the cases same object is being destryoed twice. What basically I am looking for is what exactly is changing betweeen the two cases. If you say in one case delete is getting called twice in one case and not in other case then what is deciding factor to call or not to call delete twice. I think this can not be a very generic case as delete gets called in both the cases when we just create the shared pointer by either way

Comment: I added a paragraph explaining the difference between the two constructs. However I also think you should realize that trying to explain the behavior of undefined behavior is actually pointless. You cannot even rely on it to be the same every time you run the program.